# How to switch between widgets in a table? Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-navigation

I need your help. I have a table with data in `explorer_screen`, when you click on each line, it goes to the corresponding page with detailed information about the block `block_info_screen`. So I need to add the ability to switch between these blocks, which are in the table on the details page. So that you can not return to the table and select another block, but immediately switch from `block_info_screen` to the elements following the table. As far as I understand, I need to wrap each row in the table in a push widget and use buttons and Navigator.push to switch between these widgets from the `block_info_screen` page.
Could you elaborate more on how to implement this feature?

**explorer_screen** - **here is the table**

```
 return DataTable(
                      columns: const [
                        DataColumn(label: Text('Height')),
                        DataColumn(label: Text('Hash')),
                        DataColumn(label: Text('Time')),
                      ],
                      rows: List.generate(5, (index) {
                        return DataRow(cells: [
                          DataCell(TextButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                Navigator.push(
                                    context,
                                    MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (context) => BlockInfoPage(
                                              hashBlock: blocksData[index].hash,
                                              heightBlock:
                                                  '${blocksData[index].height}',
                                            )));
                              },
                              child: Text('${blocksData[index].height}'))),
                          DataCell(Text(blocksData[index].hash)),
                          DataCell(Text('${blocksData[index].time}')),
                        ]);
                      }));
```

**block_info_screen** - here is detailed information and here you need to implement switching between data in the table

```
return Column(children: [
                          _blockInfo(blocksInfoData),
                          const SizedBox(height: 20),
                          _blockDetails(blocksInfoData),
                        ]);
```

**Buttons to be implemented on the details page**

[image]

**Here is my table and when I click on each element I get a page with detailed information. You have to switch between them.**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is you can send your whole list to the next screen i.e block screen and also the current index of the  data cell that is selected. So initially you can display the selected element and then you can manage/change your index on next and back buttons as you have the access to the whole list.

If it's tough to understand.. let me know I'll elaborate.. but i would suggest you to try this out first.

Comment: And how can I change the index of an element in the table using the button?

Comment: Can you please explain to me in more detail? )

Comment: let's say the next button is pressed.. then you can call setState and do index++; opposite for back button index--; also check whenever you press the back button that index is not less than zero and on next button that index is not greater than or equal to list.length

Comment: Hey.. quick check if it is working or not?

Comment: And how do I access the index, just as I access the data? blocksData[index]. Or do you need to pass to block_info_screen where the buttons will pass index ?

Comment: And for setState I still need to pass the widget to the StatefulWidget

Comment: I don't understand how to refer to the index in order to increase or decrease it

Comment: I added but only the data is updated but does not change 

ElevatedButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  widget.index++;
                                });
                              },
                              child: Text('Add'))